# Formating integer of year and week to datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a lot of dates in the format of

```
201801
201802
201803
...
201852
```

It is in the format YYYYWW.
I need it in any date format, so i can divide these dates into training and testphase.
For example 2018-01-01

Comment: Is the data in a text file?

Comment: Are the week numbers using the ISO definition or are they starting from January 1?

Comment: I ask because ISO weeks are non-intuitive and not trivial to calculate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **strptime()** function from **datetime** package to create the date from the strings:

```
import datetime
dateString = "201801"
dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString + '-1', "%Y%W-%w")
print(dateObject)
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This one works perfekt for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have one more question. If i want to convert a whole column of a pandas dataframe with this function it doesn't really work, as the `dateString` needs to be a string. And i can also not work with series. So how would i be able to convert a column with this function?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for,

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%W")
```

`date` is a value like `201801` as a string.